# Can I scale iframe according to the width of page?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I try to scale iframe according to the size of page.

If I visit below page in mobile then, I got desired results. (Properly scaled page)

http://www.jobautomationindex.com/skill_dna_view

[image]

However, if I load the page in iframe in below link, the page isn't rescaled.

http://www.jobautomationindex.com/skill_dna/

[image]

Why these two pages behave differently?

========================================================================

For note, here is my code

I think one solution could be related with the scale factor in css.

```
<style>    
.wrap {
    width: 400;
    height: 400;
    overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 700px !important;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>

<div class="wrap" style="width:400; height:400;">

    <iframe src="/skill_dna_view" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="700px" frameborder="0" tabindex="-1" allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this meta in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```